# getObjectsById on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

According to JDO, you can use [PersistenceManager.getObjectsById](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.html#getObjectsById%28java.util.Collection%29) to load multiple entity instances by their object id.

What kind of Collection does one need to use here? A Google Data Store Key does not work as object id.

Answer (score 3):

Use PersistenceManager.newObjectIdInstance(), as such

```
List<Object> ids = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Key key : keys) {
   ids.add(pm.newObjectIdInstance(Foo.class, key));
}

return (List<Foo>) pm.getObjectsById(ids);
```

I'm not sure however how expensive the call to newObjectIdInstance is (it shouldn't be from what I can see).

Comment: @Sam, which alternative are you comparing to? Is it more expensive than Thilo's solution? How are you evaluating how expensive this call is?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, by as an alternative to `getObjectsById`, it seems that you can use a [JDOQL query to load multiple entities by key](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/10/executing-batch-gets.html):

```
public List getById(List keys) {
   Query q = pm.newQuery(
      "select from " + Book.class.getName() + " where :keys.contains(key)");
   return (List) q.execute(keys);
}
```

Apparently, this query is optimized to use an efficient low-level bulk API.

The order of the keys does get lost though, so you will have to re-sort the result in Java land.

Comment: I am not able to make it work: Problem with query <SELECT FROM Book WHERE :keys.contains(key)>: Unsupported method <contains> while parsing expression: InvokeExpression{[ParameterExpression{keys}].contains(VariableExpression{key})}

Answer (score 0):

The answer above me is almost correct.

There seems to be a mistake in the syntax explained by Google on their developers website.

Explained by google:

> // Give me all Employees with lastName equal to Smith or Jones
>       Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class,
>                                 ":p.contains(lastName)");
>       query.execute(Arrays.asList("Smith", "Jones"));

Surely it should be:

> // Give me all Employees with lastName equal to Smith or Jones
>       Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class,
>                                 "p.contains(:lastName)");
>       query.execute(Arrays.asList("Smith", "Jones"));

Comment: The doc is correct. The ":p" is your list, and you are checking for objects whose "lastName" is contained in your list, hence <your list>.contains(<object's lastName value>).